# Attempting to use channels for synchronization causes deadlocks

Tags: go, synchronization, channel, goroutine

so I'm new to the language and I know that the usual way of waiting for multiple workers to finish is by using a WaitGroup. However, I'm not sure why my code below that uses channels for this purpose is causing a deadlock. The simplified version is as follows:

```golang
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, done chan bool) {
    
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    
    // do something with fetched data...

    // create a separate channel to wait for all workers to finish
    done_2 := make (chan bool)
    
    // create workers
    for _, u := range urls {

        go Crawl(u, depth - 1, fetcher, done_2)

    }
    
    // wait for all workers to write to the channel, which indicates their completion
    for i := 0; i < len (urls); i++ {
        fmt.Printf ("On URL %v, iteration %v\n", url, i)
        <- done_2
    }
    
    // indicate the completion of the current worker
    done <- true
    
}

func main() {
    
    done := make (chan bool)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, done)
    <- done 
}
```

The program gives the desired output, but instead of exiting after that, it enters into a deadlock.

Comment: The done_2 channel is passed as a parameter, and in the formal parameters it's labeled as "done". At the end of the function I'm writing to that channel.. so is there any problem there?

Comment: Your code (with tweaks to make it compile) seems to run OK [in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZYCFz7AhMNZ) with a simulated `Fetch` function.